# Cannot connect to MySql using PHP on Linux

Tags: linux, mysql, php

I am creating some login pages on Linux using PHP and MySql. It worked perfectly before. However, all of a sudden, I start to get the PHP code on a browser instead of the table that was displayed before.

I didn't change the code at all and the database and tables are still there, but when I log into MySql with `mysql -r root -p`, I got an error that is

> 'ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'student'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)'
>   , so I have to log into MySql with `sudo mysql -r root -p`.

**Login page (worked before):**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "phpproject";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "ProjectDb";

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
```

**Trial login page:**

```
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'phpproject');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'ProjectDb');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
```

Does anyone have any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql -r root -p` will attempt to connect to the schema `root` as the current user, with a password prompt, using raw output.  This is probably not what you intend to be doing.

Try `mysql -uphpproject -p ProjectDb`.  If that works, something is awry in your PHP configuration; if it does not, you have bad credentials.  The answer is *not* to just connect as the root user; the answer is to correct your credentials.

Comment: Thank you. I could login with 'mysql -uphpproject -p ProjectDb' without the error. However, the PHP code is displayed on a browser without displaying the proper content.
Does PHP configuration mean connection code? That worked before, but not anymore. 
How to correct my credentials?

Comment: If going to the PHP page in a browser shows you the PHP source rather than the results of its execution, that implies that your HTTP server daemon does not have its PHP module enabled, which is beyond the scope of this question.  Presuming apache, you can start with `sudo a2enmod php` perhaps.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much. so my problem is not the PHP or MySql, it is Apache. That makes sense. I will try the command that you provided. Thank you!